# ActiveAdmin and Devise - skip_confirmation! on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, confirmation, skip

I want to call `user.skip_confirmation` while his account is created by admin in admin panel. I want user to confirm his account in further steps of registration process, but not on `create`. The only idea I have is to override `create` in controller:

```
controller do
  def create
    user = User.new
    user.skip_confirmation!
    user.confirmed_at = nil
    user.save!
  end
end
```

The problem is, I have different `attr_accessible`s for standard user and admin, and it works, because ActiveAdmin uses InheritedResources:

```
attr_accessible :name, :surname
attr_accessible :name, :surname, invitation_token, :as => :admin
```

It doesn't work after I changed `create` (it worked before). How can I do what I want and still be able to use this `:as => :admin` feature?

Answer (score 3):

I look at the answer and none is solving the issue at hand. I solve it the simplest way as shown below.

```
before_create do |user|
 user.skip_confirmation!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
controller do
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user].merge({:confirmed_at => nil}))
    @user.skip_confirmation!
    create! #or super
  end

  def role_given?
    true
  end

  def as_role
    # adapt this code if you need to
    { :as => current_user.role.to_sym } 
  end
end
```

something like that could work

**EDIT**: if you define `role_given?` to return true and `as_role`, `InheritResources` will use `as_role` to get the role information

also

```
controller do
  with_role :admin
end
```

works, but this way you can't change the role given the user.

Comment: Nope, in this case `:as => :admin` doesn't work. I get `Can't mass-assign protected attributes`

Comment: Hmmm... that's what I did before and it works, unless I override `create`.

Answer (score -1):

At your /app/models/user.rb

```
  before_create :skip_confirmation

  def skip_confirmation
    self.skip_confirmation! if Rails.env.development?
  end
```

Comment: The question is about Devise, not the development environment.